# changing to right src low resolution placeholder for portrait or landscape view image with lazysizes using picture HTML element

Tags: image, lazy-loading, responsive-images

Recently I'm reading about art direction in web designing and trying to improve my knowledge about responsive images. So far I read articles about picture HTML element, how the source and img elements work within the picture element and also a few tutorials on lazysizes.js.

I catched the idea in general but just not sure about two thing; so, if I don't need art direction and only concerning about loading the same image with proper size, img tag is enough to get what we want.
However, if we want to define specific images for, let's say, landscape and portrait viewports we need to use picture HTML element. What I'm curious about is, when I look at the image names defined in srcset attributes in an img, I see that we give only width information like 320w, 480w. Does the browser check the aspect ratio of the images and refuse to load an image with different aspect ratio? Or can we just give portrait and landscape framed images in the same img tag and do the tweaks with CSS using media queries as well which will allow us to do art direction with only img elements? What makes using picture element mandatory for art direction?

My second question is, let's say I use picture HTML element to define different images for mobile devices and desktop and at the same time using lazysizes.

From what I understand, in a picture element we define only one img in which I should load my low quality placeholder image. But since I have both portrait and lanscape views in the datasrc sets, how do I tell the browser or lazysizes to load the landscape placeholder in img when it's a desktop and load the portrait view placeholder image when it's a mobile device? Because, I assume, since we can define only one img with src property in which we define our low quality placeholder image, I can only pick either a portrait or landscape framed image which will look a bit weird if browser picks the other frame option as the most suitable image. Am I wrong or am I lost in all the information bombing about the issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using different images for Portrait and Landscape maybe is not a good approach. In the end after the Lazy loading, there will be one image src loaded and if the user rotate the device and go from portrait to landscape he will not see the proper image.

There is an option to create two containers - one for portrait and one for desktop and use CSS media query (https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_media_orientation) for display none/block for the proper container. In each container you can lazy-load the proper images. The downside will be, there will be 2 images loaded.

Comment: Thanks Georgi for replying. Isn't it the main purpose of using picture element? I mean distinguishing the desktop and mobile pictures?

Comment: not a problem to distinguish desktop and mobile, but mobile has portrait and landscape, and here again you have to change them if your layout is based on the screen proportion